# I'm trying to make a trivia game with tkinter

Tags: tkinter

Im trying to make a trivia game using tkinter. if the answer is correct, the next question will be displayed along with an answer button. if the answer is wrong, then I dont want the next question and the answer btton to be displayed. how do i do that? also if the answer is wrong, then an error message will be displayed on the screen.

```
def ans2():

q7 = e2.get()
q8 = Label(root)
q8.place(x=30, y=130)
if str(q7) == "belfast":
q28.configure(text=str("congrats! you got it right!"))
q8.configure(text=str("2)What is the most widely spoken language in brazil?"))
else:
q28.configure(text=str("oops. you got it wrong."))
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), for us to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Due to lack of information in the code you provided, I have made this working sample.

```py
#Sample
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()

def next():
    global ans_entry, count
    if ans_entry.get() == key_list[count]:
        ques_label.configure(text = ques_list[count+1])
        ans_entry.delete(0, END)
        count += 1
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Incorrect', 'Sorry your answer is incorrect')

ques_list = ['Enter hey', 'Enter hello', 'Enter hola']
key_list = ['hey', 'hello', 'hola']
ques_label = Label(root)
ques_label.pack()
ans_entry = Entry(root)
ans_entry.pack()
next_button = Button(root, text = 'Next', command = next)
next_button.pack()
count = 0
ques_label.configure(text = ques_list[0])

root.mainloop()
```

I hope the logic in the code is self explanatory. Apart from that I have used `messagebox` to display the information, more information of which can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/tkinter.messagebox.html).